# Codeception Db config settings fail to be recognized

Tags: codeception

I'm getting this error when trying to run $php codeception.phar build:

> [Codeception\Exception\ModuleConfigException]
>   Db module is not configured!
>
> Options: dsn, user, password are required
>   Please, update the configuration and set all the required fields

However, I've configured my codeception.yml file:

```
modules:
    - Db:
        config:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=somePath.morePath.this.that.amazonaws.com;port=XXXX;dbname=dbName'
            user: 'myUser'
            password: 'myPassword'
            dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
            populate: false
            cleanup: false
            reconnect: true
```

I've also tried the same configuration in my api.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

You put config: and Db: in wrong order.

Correct structure is:

```
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=somePath.morePath.this.that.amazonaws.com;port=XXXX;dbname=dbName'
            user: 'myUser'
            password: 'myPassword'
            dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
            populate: false
            cleanup: false
            reconnect: true
```